# SQL - View column that calculates the percentage from other columns

Tags: sql

I have a query from Access where I caluclated the percentage score of three seperate numbers Ex:

```
AFPercentageMajor: [AFNumberOfMajors]/([AFTotalMajor]-[AFMajorNA])
```

which could have values of `20/(23-2) = 95%`

I have imported this table into my SQL database and tried to write a expression in the view (changed the names of the columns a bit)

```
AF_Major / (AF_Major_Totals - AF_Major_NA)
```

I tried adding `*100` to the end of the statement but it only works if the calculation is at 100%. If it is anything less than that it puts it as a 0.

I have a feeling it just doesn't like the combincation of the three seperate column names. But like I said I'm still learning so I could be going at this completely wrong!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server does integer division.  You need to change one of the values to a floating point representation.  The following will work:

```
cast([AFNumberOfMajors] as float)/([AFTotalMajor]-[AFMajorNA])
```

You can multiply this by 100 to get the percentage value.